# Grep data from multiple file then feed into a log in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm new to Python, hopefully someone can help me in this.
I want to grep data from multiple files then combine the data I grep into a single log.

My input files as such:

**Input file1 (200MHz)**

```
Cell_a  freq_100  50  
Cell_a  freq_200  6.8  
Cell_b  freq_100  70
```

**Input file2 (100MHz)**

Cell_a  freq_100  100
   Cell_a  freq_200  10.5
   Cell_b  freq_100  60

**This is my expected output**

[cell]  [freq] [value_frm_file1] [value_frm_file2] [value_frm_file3] [etc...]

**Example expected output:-**

Cell_a  freq_100 50 100     #50 is taken from file1, 100 from file2
   Cell_a  freq_200 6.8 10.5
   Cell_b  freq_100 70 60

I guess the best way is to store in Python dictionary? Can you give me example or show me how to do this? Here is my code, but I'm only able to get the value one at a time, how to combined them accordingly to it's respective freq type?

```
for i in cmaxFreqList: #this is the list base on it's frq type, IE 200MHz, 100MHz etc
    file = path + freqfile
    with open (file) as f:
        data = f.readlines()

    for line in data:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        freqlength = len(line.split())
        if freqlength == 3:
            searchFreqValue =re.search("(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)",line)
            cell = searchFreqValue.group(1)
            freq = searchFreqValue.group(2)
            value = searchFreqValue.group(3)
            print ('cell + ' ' + freq + ' ' + value)  #only can get up to printing out one value at a time
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a relatively simple task provided your files are not extremely huge (i.e. their combined data can fit into the working memory while concatenating them). All you need is to create a `(cell_name, freq)` map (you can use a `dict` for that) and then append the matching values to it. Once you go through all your files just write to the combined output file the `map->value` elements and Bob's your uncle:

```
import os
import collections

path = "."  # current folder
freq_list = ["100.dat", "200.dat"]  # a list of files to concatenate

result = collections.defaultdict(list)  # a map to hold a list of our results
for file_name in freq_list:  # go through each file name
    with open(os.path.join(path, file_name), "r") as f:  # open the file
        for line in f:  # go through it line by line
            try:
                cell, freq, value = line.split()  # split it by whitespace into 3 elements
            except ValueError:  # invalid line - it didn't have exactly 3 elements
                continue  # ignore the current line and continue with the next
            result[(cell, freq)].append(value)  # append the value to our result map
with open(os.path.join(path, "combined.dat"), "w") as f:  # open our output file for writing
    # Python dictionaries are unsorted (<v3.6), sort the keys when looping through them
    for element in sorted(result):  # loop through each key in our result map
        # write the key (cell name and frequency) separated by space, add space,
        # write the values separated by space and finally add a new line:
        f.write("{} {}\n".format(" ".join(element), " ".join(result[element])))
```

It's unclear from your code what `cmaxFreqList` contains, but in my example it (`freq_list`) holds the actual file names - you can of course construct your input file names any way you want (just make sure that `os.path.join(path, file_name)` constructs a valid path). For example, if the above-listed `100.dat` contained:

```
Cell_a  freq_100  50
Cell_a  freq_200  6.8
Cell_b  freq_100  70
```

and the `200.dat` contained:

```
Cell_a freq_100 100
Cell_a freq_200 10.5
Cell_b freq_100 60
```

the "combined.dat" file will end up as:

```
Cell_a freq_100 50 100
Cell_a freq_200 6.8 10.5
Cell_b freq_100 70 60
```

Comment: Thank you zwer for your sample codes that perfectly help me to solve my use case . Also I'm very much grateful as you provide the explanation for every piece of code here, I'm new to Python, will need more exercise to fully understand your code. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I dont fully understand the question due to the readability of your expected ouput, however here are some tips you could use to iterate through the parameters and the values:

for searching a type of value (i.e cell, freq, etc) you could use the list index method:

```
parameters = ['Cell_', 'freq_', 'etc'] #Name of the parameters you are looking for

for parameter in parameters:
    for line in data:
        new_list = line.split() 
        position_of_the_value = new_list.index(parameter) + 1
```

if you

```
print(new_list[position_of_the_value])
```

you get the value for that parameter in that line, you can then store it in a list

```
parameter1_list = list()
parameter1_list.append(new_list[position_of_the_value])
```

finally, you construct the string you want to print

```
print('Parameter_1 '+ ' '.join(parameter1_list))
```

and this will print something like

```
Parameter_1 100 50 200 300
```

you just have to contruct loops to iterate over every parameter and every list in order to get them all printed.

Comment: sry for that José Garcia, I just amend my question to be more readable, your sample is good but I think I should stored in dictionary so that all values of it's respective freq type to cell can be appended together?

Comment: You mean a dictionary like dict = { 'Cell_a freq100' : [value1, value2, value 3] } ? or how, if you give me an example i can help you with a way of doing it

Comment: I have no idea how the dictionary looks like but yeah my expected result  is <cell> <freq_100> <value1> <value2> <value3> <etc> in format. I really appreciate your kindness to help, I'm lucky that the sample codes that zwer provided did exactly solve my problem. I'll be glad if you're free to spend time to provide other option for my learning purpose. Thank you for your help in your earlier sample!